# update-initramfs trying to create initrd.img-new

Tags: initramfs

Ubuntu 16.04, when I try to update initramfs (or apt does), I am getting some errors. I looks like it is trying to generate a 'new' kernel version which is kicking an error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
PC:/boot$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-new
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/new
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed new
dpkg: warning: version 'new' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed new
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-23-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-23-generic
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_dFsQMd/lib/modules/4.2.0-23-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_dFsQMd/lib/modules/4.2.0-23-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-23
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.2.0-23
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.2.0-23: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_J6fvxO/lib/modules/4.2.0-23/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_J6fvxO/lib/modules/4.2.0-23/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and I fixed it like this:

```
sudo update-initramfs -d -k new
```

That should remove the bogus `/boot/initrd.img-new`. Then try your command again:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```